# Help to prove numerically the given equation below?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, definition

Consider a spectral decomposition of a unitary matrix $U$ given by $WAW^*$ where $A$ is diagonal matrix of eigen-values of $U$ and the symbol $^*$ means transconjugate. An infinitesimal shift $dU$would change the matrices by $dA$ and $dW$. Can anyone please help me to prove numerically that $WdW^*+dWW^*=0$. Any comments would be highly appreciated. I can see how Hermitian property can lead to the result but I need help to show numerically. Specifically, is there a way to compute $dW$ without any model of $W$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $U$ is normal, you can choose $W$ as a unitary matrix s.t. $U=WAW^*$ and $A$ is diagonal complex. Since $WW^*=I$, we deduce that $WdW^*+dWW^*=0$ (with the transconjugate $W^*$ and not with the transpose $W'$ !).

Comment: I see that a brave people downvoted my post without leaving his name...

Comment: @ Creator .The important thing is not the downvote, but that 1. your question is absolutely incomprehensible. 2. There is a big mistake that you do not want to correct. Thus, completely rewrite your question or I'll vote to close it.

Comment: May I ask what is it the big mistake that I do not want to correct? If I know the mistake, I will correct it or delete the question myself, thanks.

Comment: @ Cretor . I just see that $W'$ became the transconjugate !!  You really are the only one using this notation.

Comment: I did not know how to use * got it from you now. thanks. I can delete the question but since it has an answer it complains.